# Is there a general image service "unshort" api service?

Tags: image, api, url-shortener

I am currently updating my Twitter client Nymphicus to use http://unshort.me/ to unshorten all the links in tweets. Before that I implemented all the url shortener APIs myself but there are so many...

With images it is quite the same: I do implement all the different APIs out there to get thumbnails but I wonder if anyone knows a service similar to unshort.me which gives you back the url of a thumbnail if you send the image link?

Answer (score 0):

http://embed.ly/ does it, 10k requests free. otherwise it's a pay service.